# Can the units of the measure tool in QGIS be changed?

Tags: qgis, measurements

All,

I'm trying to do some error-checking with some rasters I'm creating, and want to measure line distances on the map in feet, rather than meters - which is what the measure line tool seems to be 'stuck' at.

Comment: Note that the units also depend on what base map you're using. If your base map is a WGS84 shapefile, the measuring tool units will be stuck on "degrees" regardless of what settings you have. However if it's an OpenStreetMap tiled layer using EPSG 3857, you'll be able to get more useful units.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you go to Settings -> Options there is a Map Tools tab, on that tab you change your preferred units for the measure tool from meters to feet.