# In QGIS 2.14.0 The measuring tool is set to Meters even after changing it to feet in settings

Tags: qgis, tools

I need to measure some lengths in feet, in previous versions I could change the units in the drop down window and it would stay on feet now it reverts back to meters, if you take focus off the measure tool by for example selecting the next point to measure to.

I have gone to Settings >Options >Map Tools and change the distance units to feet but the tool still opens in meters

Comment: Which version of QGIS are you using and what is your CRS?

Comment: According to this question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52583/can-the-units-of-the-measure-tool-in-qgis-be-changed , some CRS's can only handle certain units, but I would think if yours is measuring in meters there's no reason why it shouldn't be able to handle feet.

Answer (score 4):

Check your project's settings. The project also has a default distance unit which may be set to metres.

Comment: Thanks very much this is the answer the project was set to meters